# How to determine if user attempted to dismiss the sheet when .interactiveDismissDisabled is set to true?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am presenting a sheet view to the user where they can edit some information. If they indeed changed something, I am setting `.interactiveDismissDisabled(true)` to prevent user from dismissing the view while they have some unsaved changes.

To make this experience complete I also want to show a prompt along the lines of "Are you sure you want to dismiss your changes"?

I am having issues figuring out how to detect this "swipe to dismiss" attempt from user to present this prompt while also keeping `.interactiveDismissDisabled(true)` to ensure that sheet is not dismissed until user confirms the prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I can think of, is to add a very small presentation detent (in addition to the detents your sheet supports).

If the current detent changes to this very small detent, that means the user attempts to dismiss the sheet. You would then set the detent back to its original value, and show an alert, or whatever you want to do.

Here is a simple example:

```
@State var sheet = false
@State var alert = false
@State var currentDetent = PresentationDetent.large

var body: some View {
    Button("Show Sheet") {
        sheet = true
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $sheet) {
        Text("Sheet Content")
            .interactiveDismissDisabled()
            .presentationDetents([.large, .height(1)], selection: $currentDetent)
            .onChange(of: currentDetent) { oldValue, newValue in
                if newValue == .height(1) {
                    alert = true
                    currentDetent = oldValue
                }
            }
            .alert("Are you sure?", isPresented: $alert) {
                Button("Yes") {
                    sheet = false
                }
                Button("No") {}
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as changes are detected, you could disable scrolling and use a `DragGesture` to detect a swipe. Then you can prompt for confirmation.

Something like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    struct FormValues: Equatable {
        var aFlag = false
        var text = ""
    }

    @State private var isSheetShowing = false
    @State private var isAlertshowing = false
    @State private var formValues = FormValues()
    @State private var hasChanges = false
    @State private var dragOffset = CGFloat.zero

    var body: some View {
        Button("Show sheet") {
            isSheetShowing = true
        }
        .buttonStyle(.bordered)
        .sheet(isPresented: $isSheetShowing) {
            Form {
                Toggle("On or off", isOn: $formValues.aFlag)
                TextField(text: $formValues.text) {
                    Text("Text")
                }
            }
            .offset(y: dragOffset)
            .animation(.easeInOut, value: dragOffset)
            .interactiveDismissDisabled(hasChanges)
            .scrollDisabled(hasChanges)
            .onAppear { hasChanges = false }
            .onChange(of: formValues) { oldVal, newVal in
                hasChanges = true
            }
            .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { val in
                        if hasChanges {
                            dragOffset = val.translation.height
                        }
                    }
                    .onEnded { val in
                        if hasChanges && dragOffset > 0 {
                            isAlertshowing = true
                        }
                        dragOffset = 0
                    }
            )
            .confirmationDialog("Are you sure?", isPresented: $isAlertshowing) {
                Button("Yes") {
                    isSheetShowing = false
                    // Save changes
                }
                Button("No", role: .cancel) {
                    // Do nothing
                }
            } message: {
                Text("Are you sure?")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works, but I found there is an issue after an alert choice is selected. The alert disappears but then re-appears, before disappearing a second time. You may find that this happens with other forms of solution too.

Also, if the user needs to scroll to reach the end of the form then of course it may not be possible to disable scrolling.